# using localhost via VPN

Tags: drupal-7, localhost, vpn

I am connected to a remote server via VPN (lets call it server A). From that server I connect to a virtual server via SSH (lets call this one server B). I have installed lamp and drupal on server B but I cant figure out how to verify that the installation was completed successfully. I thought that looking into localhost would do the trick but the browser says it cant connect to the server.
Have I done something wrong? Should I use some GUI remote connection tool (if there is one ?).
How can I open sites created with drupal in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was probably somewhere in my mac, I have restarted it and there was no problem to connect via VPN no more.